# Access Database After Insert running before the Insert

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is not my true problem, but a (hopefully) reproducible example. I am using Access 2013.

### Question

How do I make an Append query to truly run After Insert and After Delete? The query appears to be using the table prior to the Insert/Delete being committed.

### Setup

- `table1` has two fields: `ID_Record` and `Record`
- `table2` has one field: `ID_Record`
- `query1` is an Append query, to insert `table1.ID_Record` into `table2`

For `table1`, I have added events for After Insert and After Delete. They call the following Named Macro (I followed the answer from another question for this - it seems to work, but I am not sure if it is set up 100% correctly).

**SetLocalVar**

- Name: `TempVar`
- Expression: `=DeleteThenRun("table2", "query1")`

The function below `DeleteThenRun()` first deletes all of the records in `table2` and then runs `query1` to append from `table1` into `table2`.

### What I am Seeing

This triggers and almost works. The problem I am having is that this seems to lag behind by one record. If I have 1 record in `table1` and then add another, `table2` will have only that first record, and not the new one based on the trigger. If I then go and manually delete the records in `table2` and then manually run `query1`, I will get both records (i.e., the Append query is working correctly).

If from there I go to `table1` and delete the second record, the macro will fire again, delete the table, but then `table2` has both records in it, while I would expect it to have only one.

Adding in breakpoints shows me a bit what is going on. The function will run before Access pops up the box asking me to confirm delete. So I think that `query1` is being ran before the insert or delete is being committed, but I do not know how to change that.

The odd thing for my theory is that the `Debug.Print` line writes out the `RecordCount` that I expect (which is not the record count that gets Appended).

```
Public Function DeleteThenRun(DeleteFrom As String, RunQuery As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo lnError
    
    Dim wrk As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    
    Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    Set db = CurrentDb

    wrk.BeginTrans
    db.Execute "DELETE * FROM " & DeleteFrom & ";", dbFailOnError
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print db.TableDefs("table1").RecordCount
    db.QueryDefs(RunQuery).Execute dbFailOnError
    
    wrk.CommitTrans
    Set db = Nothing
    Set wrk = Nothing
    
    DeleteThenRun = True
    Exit Function
    
lnError:
    wrk.Rollback
    Set db = Nothing
    Set wrk = Nothing
    
    DeleteThenRun = False
End Function
```

Comment: How are you adding that missing record - form data entry? Make sure record is committed to table before running the action queries: `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False`.

Comment: 1. What you are doing is not recommended at all!(have you ever thought about what would happen if you insert 100 records at once?)
2. Post the `query1`.

Comment: @krishKM Yes, I know my use case and business processes very well. I have some weird things due to a highly constrained and restricted environment (which is forcing me into Access to begin with). This table will get maybe 2-3 records per month added too it.

Comment: Any query he runs is unrelated to the question.  There's some interesting action going on between tableDefs, the actual table and running a VBA udf from the After Insert event on a table.  Doing some testing - pulling the RecordSet directly from TableDefs("table1").OpenRecordset returns the correct amount of rows. Any other attempt at accessing the table - via db.OpenRecordset("table1") or OpenRecordset("select * from table1") or a simply query against table1 only returns 9 records.  Question is why does the event fire first before the full commit to the table? CommitTrans doesn't solve it.

Comment: @Mike that is what I am seeing, though I am not an Access power user and just assume I am doing something wrong, somewhere. @June7 I am just operating on the table itself. I think `Me.Dirty` is exactly what I want if I move data to a form, so I will play with that. I am actually using R to load data from Excel templates into Access. There is a summary table that I wanted to calculate after each insert. I am rethinking the workflow - I think I will just have R trigger the Append query instead.